# Displaying information, in a grid layout, fetched from an API using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, grid

How can I display data fetched from an API onto different elements which are laid out in a grid, wherein every element of the grid has different data elements in it ,each having different values?

This would have been a breeze in Android but I am relatively new to javascript, so any help would be appreciated. :) 
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very vague. What kind of data is being fetched from the API? What data structure are you using?

Comment: The data is mostly textual and stored in the form of nested arrays. I am not using any ds right now  as I am still deciding what approach to take, because the number of elements is huge.

Comment: You may be looking for the [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. If your API returns an array, you can `map` over its child objects and do something with each (like show the values in a table).

Comment: Array.map() might help me. I am trying to build a product catalog page where elements are laid in a grid and the data I am fetching from the API is in JSON format. How can I set values for all those different product items as each of them have different values?